# Intuitive method to write a matrix in one basis in terms of another basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

I'm a math undergrad studying linear algebra. I often encounter problems like this:

*Say we have a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ written in standard coordinates. I want to write $A$ in terms of non-standard coordinates. What is $A$?*

While I can solve these problems by diagraming out a series of transformations and applying the change of basis formula, all of these methods feel very mechanical. While I understand the algebra and the formula (at least a little), I don't have such a strong grasp of the intuition behind rewriting matrices that this type of problem is automatic for me yet.

For people more experienced with linear algebra, how do you approach these problems intuitively?

Thanks

Comment: the concept of a basis of a vector space is not so intuitive. Indeed the word "algebra" is advising you for no intuition at all, as algebraic methods is the way we can do mathematics without the need of intuition (I understand here "intuition" for imagination or geometric). Maybe the more intuitive thing it can be said about a change of basis is that its like translate something written in a language to other language

Comment: If you want intuition, check out [Essence of Linear Algebra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2LTAUO1TdA&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab&index=13).

Comment: @TheoBendit That series doesn't really address changes of basis